# Opera Next extension autoupdate via update_url

Tags: opera, opera-extension

I got problem with my company internal extension. They don't want to publish it, as it does gather data on external server. So I need to host it myself... but would like not to lose ability of autoupdate.

As far as I read I need to use `update_url` in manifest, but nothing more is said in Opera documentation...

`"update_url": "http://path/to/updateInfo.xml",` - as it is said in [documentation page](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/manifest.html)

Ok... and what should I put in that xml? Will it autoupdate or just notify users about new updates? Where do I put rest of updated files?

I tried to concat Opera itself about this question, but they don't give any contact information except something like `if you have problem, ask on stackoverflow`... so here I am.

If it does not work, I was thinking about really BAD method, using `unsafe-eval` and keeping newest version in local storage... but would rather like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the behavior is the same as for Chrome. You can base on this document: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate